# jquery adding variables to href attribute

Tags: jquery, href, attr

I'm sure this is probably something simple I'm overlooking but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<h1 class="entry-title">Installation Maintenance and Detailed Inspection</h1>
<div class="ai1ec-time">
    <div class="ai1ec-label">When:</div>
    <div class="ai1ec-field-value">January 13, 2014</div>
</div>
<div class="ai1ec-location">
    <div class="ai1ec-label">Where:</div>
    <div class="ai1ec-field-value">MOXI Perth</div>
</div>
<div class="ai1ec-cost">
    <div class="ai1ec-label">Cost:</div>
    <div class="ai1ec-field-value">AU$3200</div>    
</div>
<a id="booklink" title="Training Enrolement Form" href="http://www.moxi.com.au/training-enrolement-form/">Book Now!</a>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var bookcourse = jQuery(".entry-title").html;
    var booktime =  jQuery(".ai1ec-time .ai1ec-field-value").html;
    var booklocation =  jQuery(".ai1ec-location .ai1ec-field-value").html;
    var bookcost =  jQuery(".ai1ec-cost .ai1ec-field-value").html;
    jQuery("#booklink").attr('href',"http://www.moxi.com.au/training-enrolement-form?title="+bookcourse+"&cost="+bookcost+"&date="+booktime+"&location="+booklocation);
});
</script>
```

Goal is to have the href attribute come out as:

```
http://www.moxi.com.au/training-enrolement-form?title=Installation Maintenance and Detailed Inspection&cost=AU$3200&date=January 13, 2014&location=MOXI Perth
```

Comment: why not use `text()` ? you will even include html markup on the link if you will use `html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) is a method not a property, so you need to use `.html()` not `.html`

```
var bookcourse = jQuery(".entry-title").html();
var booktime =  jQuery(".ai1ec-time .ai1ec-field-value").html();
var booklocation =  jQuery(".ai1ec-location .ai1ec-field-value").html();
var bookcost =  jQuery(".ai1ec-cost .ai1ec-field-value").html();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D3cDY/)

Comment: Yep... something stupid like that. Definitely shows I've been staring at this for way too long.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var bookcourse = $(".entry-title").html();
var booktime =  $(".ai1ec-time .ai1ec-field-value").html();
var booklocation =  $(".ai1ec-location .ai1ec-field-value").html();
var bookcost =  $(".ai1ec-cost .ai1ec-field-value").html();
jQuery("#booklink").attr('href', "http://www.moxi.com.au/training-enrolement-form?title=" + bookcourse + "&cost=" + bookcost + "&date=" + booktime + "&location=" + booklocation);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var href = $("#booklink").attr("href");
if (href.substr(0, href.length - 1) == "/") {
    href = href.substr(0, href.length - 1);
}
href += "?title=" + $(".entry-title").text();
href += "?cost=" + $(".ai1ec-cost .ai1ec-field-value").text();
href += "?date=" + $(".ai1ec-time .ai1ec-field-value").text();
href += "?location=" + $(".ai1ec-location .ai1ec-field-value").text();
$("#booklink").attr("href", href);
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/hx6zS/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

you can use `.text()` method also

```
$(document).ready(function()
    var bookcourse = $(".entry-title").html();
    var booktime = $(".ai1ec-time .ai1ec-field-value").html();
    var booklocation = $(".ai1ec-location .ai1ec-field-value").html();
    var bookcost = $(".ai1ec-cost .ai1ec-field-value").html();
    $("#booklink").attr('href', "http://www.moxi.com.au/training-enrolement-form?title=" + bookcourse + "&cost=" + bookcost + "&date=" + booktime + "&location=" + booklocation);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.html()` is a method and you must invoke it as a method so you must write

`jQuery(".entry-title").html();`

and aside from it `.html()` **returns all the html markup inside an element**, I think you must use `text()` instead so text will be only included in your url

http://api.jquery.com/text/